# Combine Java 8 predicates with disjunction

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

Suppose I have an array or a list of status, and want to filter a list for elements whose status matches any of the given. So I go on creating a predicate. I started by initializing it with the comparison to the first, then adding more conditions with `or`, which resulted in the minimal predicate but was a lot of code:

```
Predicate<Rec> predicate = null;
for (SendStatus status : statuss) {
    Predicate<Rec> innerPred = nr -> nr.getStatus() == status;
    if (predicate == null)
        predicate = innerPred;
    else
        predicate = predicate.or(innerpred);
}
```

More elegantly, I came up with the following code:

```
Predicate<Rec> predicate = nr -> false;
for (SendStatus status : statuss) {
    predicate = predicate.or(nr -> nr.getStatus() == status);
}
```

This looks nicer, but has a useless predicate at the beginning of the chain. Apache Collections had an `AnyPredicate` that could be composed of any number of predicates, and I’m basically looking for a replacement.

Is this superfluous predicate acceptable? Is there an even more elegant way to write this?

Comment: why not use `Predicate<Rec> predicate = nr -> statuss.contains(nr .getStatus()) ;` ?

Comment: Hey @Jerry06, you are perfectly right in this case (and I changed my code to use exactly that). However, I let the question stand for the more general case.

Answer (score 3):

How about this, assuming `statuss` is a `Collection<SendStatus>`:

```
Predicate<Rec> predicate = nr -> statuss.stream().anyMatch(status -> nr.getStatus() == status);
```

Or this, if `statuss` is a `SendStatus[]`:

```
Predicate<Rec> predicate = nr -> Arrays.stream(statuss).anyMatch(status -> nr.getStatus() == status);
```

Or do as [suggested by @Jerry06 in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992857/combine-java-8-predicates-with-disjunction/39993116#comment67263844_39992857), which is faster if `statuss` is a `Set<SendStatus>`, and simpler than streaming collection solution above:

```
Predicate<Rec> predicate = nr -> statuss.contains(nr.getStatus());
```

Comment: Since my question is “Combine Java 8 predicates with disjunction”, this may address the wrong problem. It feels a bit weird to create a stream each time the predicate is invoked.

Comment: You are also asking "Is there an even more elegant way to write this?". This answer gave you three options to choose from. And the last example is (IMHO) as elegant as it gets.